# getDay() doesn't work client-side after having sent date to the server

Tags: javascript, socket.io

This works perfectly fine on the client-side, at first:

```js
var timeOfMessageSent = new Date();
console.log(timeOfMessageSent); // Mon May 22 2017 14:03:13 GMT+0200 (Romance Summer Time)
var day = timeOfMessageSent.getDay(); // 1
console.log("this is the day: ",day);
```

However, after having sent the date to the server, and then sent it back to the client, it doesn't work.

Now the date is displayed like this: `2017-05-22T12:03:13.437Z`
I guess that's why getDate doesn't work.

How do I make sure that the date is displayed like at first? e.g. `2017-05-22T12:03:13.437Z`

Comment: It seems like your `Date` object gets replaced with its ISO string representation somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your server date string to date object.

```js
var timeOfMessageSent = new Date();
console.log(timeOfMessageSent); // Mon May 22 2017 14:03:13 GMT+0200 (Romance Summer Time)
var day = timeOfMessageSent.getDay(); // 1
console.log("this is the day: ",day);

var newDate = new Date("2017-05-25T12:19:55.982Z"); // give your server date and return as date object
var newDay = newDate.getDay();
console.log("this is the new day: ", newDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the date gets returned by the server as an ISO string. You have to create a new `Date` instance from this string.

Using strings to create date objects are usually discouraged, but an ISO date string is standard and the safest date string format to initialize a date object from.

A Javascript date object is not something that can be part of JSON, so it needs to be converted to a string or a number in order to be transmitted through a JSON API. That's why the server returns this ISO string representation of the date.
An alternative to ISO string commonly used by JSON APIs is to convert the date to a number representing the milliseconds of the date. Both varieties can be converted back to a Javascript date object with the date constructor: `new Date(dateValue)`

Comment: Ok. How would you create new Date instance from the string?

Comment: @JonasSH With the date constructor: `new Date(dateString)`

Answer (score 0):

The ISO string you get back can be modified to your preference using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). With that library you can show the date however you want.